# Beginner in C: Can't properly printf first and last element in double array?

Tags: arrays, c, debugging

I'm trying to display a Wish List on the command line. The user enters the cost of the item, the level of priority (1-3), and whether or not it has financing options (y/n). The inputted values are put in multiple arrays. After the user enters all their values, they're displayed in a table at the end.

Everything in my code works fine except when I try to printf the user inputed cost values (double itemCosts[numOfItems];) in the table. **The first and last element don't print properly**, even when I input the same price (6225.88) for all of them. The last element is just 0.000000. See included pic of table output.

I tried debugging the issue by separating the cost-related loops and compiling/running them as another file and the costs display correctly...so I'm thinking the bug is somewhere else, but I can't find it.

[image]

```
#define MAX_ITEMS 10

#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    const double MIN_INCOME = 500, MAX_INCOME = 400000;
    int numOfItems;
    double netIncome, itemTotal;
    double itemCosts[numOfItems];
    int itemPriors[numOfItems];
    char itemFinOps[numOfItems];

    printf("+--------------------------+\n");
    printf("+   Wish List Forecaster   |\n");
    printf("+--------------------------+\n\n");

    // Prompt for net monthly income
    do
    {
        printf("Enter your monthly NET income: $");
        scanf("%lf", &netIncome);
        if (netIncome < MIN_INCOME)
        {
            printf("ERROR: You must have a consistent monthly income of at least $500.00\n\n");
        }
        else if (netIncome > MAX_INCOME)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Liar! I'll believe you if you enter a value no more than $400000.00\n\n");
        }
    } while (!(netIncome >= MIN_INCOME && netIncome <= MAX_INCOME));

    printf("\n");

    // Prompt for # of wish list items
    do
    {
        printf("How many wish list items do you want to forecast?: ");
        scanf("%d", &numOfItems);

        if (!(numOfItems > 0 && numOfItems <= MAX_ITEMS))
        {
            printf("ERROR: List is restricted to between 1 and 10 items.\n\n");
        }

        printf("\n");
    } while (!(numOfItems > 0 && numOfItems <= MAX_ITEMS));

    // Store wish list item details
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++)
    {
        printf("Item-%d Details:\n", i + 1);

        do //////////////// ******** PROMPT COST ********** //////////
        {
            printf("Item cost: $");
            scanf("%lf", &itemCosts[i]);
            if (!(itemCosts[i] >= (double)100))
            {
                printf("   ERROR: Cost must be at least $100.00\n");
            }
        } while (!(itemCosts[i] >= (double)100));

        do // prompt priority
        {
            printf("How important is it to you? [1=must have, 2=important, 3=want]: ");
            scanf("%d", &itemPriors[i]);
            if (!(itemPriors[i] >= 1 && itemPriors[i] <= 3))
            {
                printf("   ERROR: Value must be between 1 and 3\n");
            }
        } while (!(itemPriors[i] >= 1 && itemPriors[i] <= 3));

        do // prompt finance options
        {
            printf("Does this item have financing options? [y/n]: ");
            scanf(" %c", &itemFinOps[i]);
            if (!(itemFinOps[i] == 'y' || itemFinOps[i] == 'n'))
            {
                printf("   ERROR: Must be a lowercase 'y' or 'n'\n");
            }
        } while (!(itemFinOps[i] == 'y' || itemFinOps[i] == 'n'));

        printf("\n");
    }

    ///////// display summary of item details in TABLE //////////
    printf("Item Priority Financed        Cost\n");
    printf("---- -------- -------- -----------\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < numOfItems; j++)
    {
        printf("  %d      %d        %c    %lf\n", j + 1, itemPriors[j], itemFinOps[j], itemCosts[j]);
        itemTotal += itemCosts[j];
    }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: These declarations     double itemCosts[numOfItems];
    int itemPriors[numOfItems];
    char itemFinOps[numOfItems]; have undefined behavior because the variable numOfItems is not initialized.

Comment: chickpea, Aside: Simplify: `(double)100` --> `100.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int numOfItems;
    double netIncome, itemTotal;
    double itemCosts[numOfItems];
    int itemPriors[numOfItems];
    char itemFinOps[numOfItems];
```

It is undefined behaviour as your `numOfItems` is not inilized. In C table will not grow or shrink to the size when you change this variable

Change to:

```
double itemCosts[MAX_ITEMS];
int itemPriors[MAX_ITEM];
char itemFinOps[MAX_ITEM];
```

Always check the result of `scanf`. Exmaple:

```
if(scanf("%lf", &netIncome) != 1){ /* handle error*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad from Moscow and 0___________ said, you cannot define an array using a not initialised variable for the number of its elements. You can define the variables as

```
double *itemCosts;
int *itemPriors;
char *itemFinOps;
```

and after the variable `numOfItems` is given a value, you dynamically allocate memory as follows:

```
itemCosts = (double*) malloc(numOfItems * sizeof(double));
itemPriors = (int*) malloc(numOfItems * sizeof(int));
itemFinOps = (char*) malloc(numOfItems * sizeof(char));
```

or

```
itemCosts = (double*) calloc(numOfItems, sizeof(double));
itemPriors = (int*) calloc(numOfItems, sizeof(int));
itemFinOps = (char*) calloc(numOfItems, sizeof(char));
```

calloc initialises all elements of array to 0

At the end you must free the allocated memory:

```
free(itemCosts);
free(itemPriors);
free(itemFinOps);
```

Comment: You will have to do it and free on every interation

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer